# How to add object to existing class Code in DART

Tags: dart

I have a class from the package which I must don't edit.

```
class A{
   int x;
}
```

I want to add the object to this class by extension or another way.

```
extension AclassExtension on A{
  static TextEditingController _myController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController get myController => _myController;
}
```

but I need without static object because each object must get a new instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Expando`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Expando-class.html) class for this:

```
class A {
  int x = 0;
}

extension AclassExtension on A {
  static final _stringValueExpando = Expando<String>();

  String? get myString => _stringValueExpando[this];
  set myString(String? value) => _stringValueExpando[this] = value;
}

void main() {
  final a = A();

  a.myString = 'test';
  print(a.myString); // test
}
```

The great thing with `Expando` is that any data attached to a object will be garbage collected together with the object itself. So no need to manually handle this memory.